# Sequence diverging to infiinity definition question

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a real sequence

I know a definition for a sequence to diverge to infinity, that being: if for all m ∈ real numbers, exists N ∈ natural numbers :

$a_n > m , n≥N$

**Is the following definition a proper definition for a real sequence to diverge to infinity as well?**

For all m ∈ real numbers, exists $a_n$ ∈ real numbers :
$a_n > m $

Otherwise, I would like some clarification, please.

Comment: No. Consider $a_n$ such that $a_{2n}=0$ and $a_{2n+1}=n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Then $a_n$ does not converge to $\infty$, but satisfies your "definition".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No take the sequence
$$
a_n=(-1)^nn.
$$
Under your proposed definition this sequence diverges to infinity (but it clearly does not).